# Linq to SQL SP parameters

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, overloading

I have a SP which I want to call from linq. The SP have 5 parameters but i only want to pass/need to 2 of them.

how would I call the SP as when i go to add the parameters in code it wont build as it want all 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have something like this:

```
MyDbDataContext db = new MyDbDataContext();

db.MyStoredProc(customerID, "sometext", null, null, null);
```

Success/failure would depend on the SQL statements inside your sproc dealing with nulls on those last 3 parameters.

Comment: does LinqToSql make the arguments nullable types automatically?  I can't remember.  If not, this wont work.

Comment: Yes, LinqToSql will make them nullable types (assuming the field is nullable).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to drag the stored proc into your DBML a second time and delete the parameters you don't want to pass in.

Comment: Same as my approach but sexier since the UI does it for you, not bad.

Comment: There is an important behavior difference.  In the case of non-nullable values, passing in 0s as you suggest would override any default values set within the stored proc declaration.

Answer (score 1):

**[overload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overloading)** the sproc call.

I dont have it in front of me but you'd goto your DataAccessName.cs file and create a method name with the same signature

auto gen'd sproc method signature:

```
void sp_sproc(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e);
```

you'd make this in your DataAccessName.cs file

```
void sp_sproc(int a, int b)
{
    this.sp_sproc(a,b,0,0,0);
}
```

if the params are nullable, like so

```
void sp_sproc(int? a, int? b, int? c, int? d, int? e);
```

then you could do

```
void sp_sproc(int a, int b)
{
    this.sp_sproc(a,b,null,null,null);
}
```